# How can I use my 3.5” disk drive without having to insert a floppy in my 5.25” drive as well?

Tags: floppy

I have some troubles to correctly install a 5.25" floppy drive in a old (1999) computer.

The drives are set this way:

1. A: 3.5" floppy @ 1.44 MB
2. B: 5.25" floppy @ 1.2 MB (Panasonic JU-475-2)
3. C: 30 GB HDD
4. D: 30 GB HDD
5. E: CD/DVD-ROM

The A: and B: drives in the BIOS are correctly configured (1.44 MB for A: and 1.2 MB for B:). Both drives are on the same controller and they are correctly connected (B: is connected to the middle connector of the cable).

At first I had a problem: when I accessed A: or B: both drives would "fire" simultaneously. I discovered that the old 5.25 drive had a series of jumpers and the drive was set as 1st drive. I switched the drive to be second drive and now I can (almost) use both drives correctly.

Now with my problem: I can only access A: if a floppy is in B: and vice-versa. For example I have a diskette in A: and none in B: if I go to A: I will have an "Abort Retry Fail" message. If I have a floppy in B: and a diskette in A: and I go to A:, I can browse the content of A: correctly and if I go to B:, I see the content of B: correctly too.

So my only problem is that now I can only use A: or B: if both drives have a diskette/floppy in it...

I guess it's another jumper thing on B: that is incorrectly set... Anyone have an idea?

I found out some jumpers diagrams if it helps someone:

- [Floppy drive Jumper question](http://www.classiccmp.org/pipermail/cctalk/1999-March/122818.html)
- [Panasonic JU-475](http://support.dell.com/support/edocs/dta/26590/)
- [5.25" floppy disk drives](http://www.docstoc.com/docs/25130082/525-FLOPPY-DISK-DRIVES) (see page 12)

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like the cable is maybe the wrong type, or you should use the other connectors (swap). There are some directions here: 
http://www.pcguide.com/proc/config/fdd-c.html

Does your cable have the twist?

Comment: This is stretching my memory but I seem to recall that if there is a twist in the cable, BOTH drives should be set as A: as the twist sorts out the addressing so this might be worth checking.

Comment: @Jamie Cox I can't switch the connector types since 5.25" and 3.5" uses different connectors. If I swap the positions of the drives on the cable A: becomes B: and B: bocomes A: (which is normal). Yes the cable is of the correct type and have a twist at the end.

Comment: @Linker3000 Thanks for the info, I will to find more on this. Gotta love vintage hardware that predate the Internet :) It's hard to find documentation!

Comment: Make sure the twisted end is near the drives and not at the end plugged into the system board.

Comment: ..oh and with a bit of digging I see both drives have to be set as B: on a cable with a twist, not A: See: http://pinouts.ru/Storage/InternalDisk_pinout.shtml

Comment: @Linker3000: The twist is correctly set near the "master" (A:) drive not the board.

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try, by setting the jumpers DS1, DS2 and TM as shown below:

```
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
3.5" drive:
DS1         OFF         Drive select 1
Attach at first connector           ALREADY DONE
```

```
BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB
5.25" drive
DS2       ON        Drive select 2
TM jumper OFF
Attach at second connector          ALREADY DONE
```